# Close the Inflated layout on click on button

Tags: android

I want to close this inflated layout when click on button of inflated layout. How to achieve this please help me.

```
li = LayoutInflater.from(VMAdjustFrame.this);
promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.wishlist_save_prompt, null);
alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(VMAdjustFrame.this);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
alertDialogBuilder.show();

TextView textView = (TextView)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setText(context.getString(R.string.share_photo));
```

Listener is called when click on email button

```
Button emailButton = (Button)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.phoneButton);
emailButton.setText(context.getString(R.string.share_photo_email));
emailButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at these two lines for changes

1. Create a **AlertDialog** Object (instance) from your `alertDialogBuilder.show()` method.

   ```
   AlertDialog dialog = alertDialogBuilder.show();
   ```
2. Using that Instance call `dismiss()` method for **AlertDialog** to hide it.

   ```
   emailButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
   ```

**Update:**

Actually you are inflating View and set it to **AlertDialog** so you have to close that **AlertDialog** to hide that inflated View.